# IE not seeing jquery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a simple test page, but suddenly, it doesn't work in IE. Can anyone see what the matter is?

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert('here');
}); //end program
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your test page is not on a server, but viewed locally from a folder, IE will oftentimes not include external JavaScript. This may be the case here.

Comment: I changed it to point to a local file:

Comment: <script src="jquery.js"></script> but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script language="javascript">
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, the mime type should be set by the server

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
<script language='javascript'>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

`<script language="JavaScript">` is deprecated. `<script type="text/javascript">` is the correct syntax

Comment: beat ya by 2 seconds ;)  +1 anyway though

Comment: @Brad You're deserved +1 too :)

Comment: Made the change, but still nothing happens.

Comment: @LauraNMS Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to replicate your problem so we can help you more?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

The language=javascript is now depreciated and you must use type=text/javascript.

You can find this in the HTML Specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

**type**: This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript"). Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute.

**language**: Deprecated. This attribute specifies the scripting language of the contents of this element. Its value is an identifier for the language, but since these identifiers are not standard, this attribute has been deprecated in favor of type.

So your correct code would be:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
alert('here');
}); //end program
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I flinch to say this, but somehow I had clicked disable script on IE, probably in an effort to use use the "select element by click" function.

Thanks everyone for your help1